# Charterstone - Does "Gain card type" via a building include the Market

Tags: charterstone

Charterstone is a legacy game, so I'm trying to avoid specific spoilers. Please excuse the roundabout phrasing.

After playing the first game of Charterstone a number of new buildings and advancement card types are unlocked within the game. Generally these new advancement card types come with a building that allows you to get them directly. The behaviour of which is clarified [After Game 1](https://stonemaiergames.com/games/charterstone/faq/) section of the FAQ.

At least two of these have corresponding Persona card. These Persona cards give you a benefit if you "gain the card from using a building". Does this mean only the specific building that grants those card types, or does using the general "Market" building to gain advancement cards also trigger this bonus?

> [image: Brewer]

Comment: If you want to be more direct in your question you can use spoiler tags.  That way you can avoid roundabout questioning and only those that want to read the full details will do. details can be found here https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @StartPlayer it's a good point. Though thinking it over, the only way to be more direct would be by naming one of the card type and building involved and then spoiler blocking the whole thing. I will update with a spoiler blocked specific example when I get home and have the card numbers in front of me.

Comment: @Jontia, can you tell, which card numbers were these personas?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh one example would be the brewer persona on card 327.

Comment: 327 does not do "gain the card from using a building". You only gain 1VP and $1 from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So digging out the card number gave me another way to search and I found this thread on [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1879351/article/27374716#27374716), specifying this exact card with a quote from the designer saying that using the general Market building would trigger the bonus from this persona.

> "whenever you use a building to gain X", it doesn't matter if the X is printed on the building or not, as there are other ways to trigger X.

It also references the FAQ that @AndrewSavinykh used to reach their answer.

> So it's different than the example in the FAQ, with refers to something in Game 1 (very minor spoiler) where you have a card that says something like, "Whenever you use a building with a brick cost, gain 1 VP." That's referring to the printed cost on the building.

Additionally for what it's worth, after feeling this was important enough to risk spoilers I pushed forward into game 2 on the app and triggered the same behaviour. The persona bonus was granted when collecting a card from the Advancement mat via the Market.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly the [AfterGame 1](https://stonemaiergames.com/games/charterstone/faq/) section you linked says:

> Persona cards: The first persona card with an ability that each player receives will say something like, “After using a building with a pumpkin cost, gain 1 VP” (the exact resource will vary). This ability only applies when the *printed* cost on the building includes at least 1 pumpkin icon, not buildings with the “any resource” icon. It is possible to have persona cards that don’t look like your original persona. Also, you may only mark personas as used if you actually use their ability during the game. *This wording on Rule 5 (card 15) is a little ambiguous.*

It looks to me, that if the persona specify advancement card type, but you are using Market which does not give the exact card type, you do not get the bonus.

Comment: Cost and gain are a little different, but it is solid reasoning.

Comment: @Jontia well, in 327 you gave as an example, it's a cost, not gain.

Comment: Good point, although it is a gain from the building being used as a cost for a second effects, which is probably why I was confused in my comment.

Comment: I'm not sure about accepting yet. I'll give a day or so, just in case your answer sparks someone else's thinking. But definately have an upvote.